# CSS menu with parallelogram shapes and submenu

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a menu with submenu like this:

[image]

- Diagonal border between options
- Parallelogram shape on hover
- The submenu a simple rectangle with options

The problem is if I use skew the text and submenu is also skewed.
Any idea how to solve this?

Some base code here: https://codepen.io/vichid/pen/cHnmK

```css
@import url( 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css' );

nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 0;
}

ul.menu {
    width: 940px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: auto;
    background-color: #AFF8C4;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul.menu li {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}

ul.menu li:hover {
    background-color: #9CE0C9;
    -moz-transition-property: background-color;
    -o-transition-property: background-color;
    -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
    transition-property: background-color;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
    transition-duration: 0.33s;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul.menu li:hover ul {
    width: 940px;
    background: #9CE0C9;
    visibility: visible;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition-property: opacity;
    -o-transition-property: opacity;
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
    transition-duration: 0.33s;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul.menu li a {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul.menu a, ul.sub-menu a {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #0E0500;
    padding: 0 10px;
}

ul.sub-menu {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #9CE0C9;
}
```

```html
<!-- nav>ul.menu>li*7>a[href="#"]{Item $}+ul.sub-menu>li*7>a[href="#"]{Sub-item $} -->
    
<nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 3</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 4</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 5</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 6</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 7</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: @vel Your menu does **exactly** what the OP noted they **don't** want to happen, skewing the sub menu - [**your menu with sub menu**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmrxqW).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the shape with a pseudo element on the `li` when hovered and then skew it.

```css
@import url('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css');
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
  right: 0;
}

ul.menu {
  width: 940px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #AFF8C4;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul.menu li {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

ul.menu > li:after {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: skew( -15deg);
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #9CE0C9;
  -moz-transition-property: background-color;
  -o-transition-property: background-color;
  -webkit-transition-property: background-color;
  transition-property: background-color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul.menu > li:hover::after {
  display: block;
}

ul.menu > li:hover ul {
  width: 940px;
  background: #9CE0C9;
  visibility: visible;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(enabled=false);
  opacity: 1;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -o-transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.33s;
  transition-duration: 0.33s;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

ul.menu li a {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul.menu a,
ul.sub-menu a {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #0E0500;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

ul.sub-menu {
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #9CE0C9;
}
```

```html
<!-- nav>ul.menu>li*7>a[href="#"]{Item $}+ul.sub-menu>li*7>a[href="#"]{Sub-item $} -->

<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 3</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 5</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 6</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Item 7</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub-item 7</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Great. Any idea for diagonal border?

Comment: Add a border like you normally would to the pseudo element.

Comment: Using a li:before like border-left: 1px solid gray; + skew seems working. Thanks! :)

Comment: Just want to be clear that you don't have to use `:after` for the shape and `:before` for the border. You can just use one pseudo element, either one is fine.

Comment: Sure. I used :before, and border none for first-of-type, to have borders only between the items.

Comment: Okay, didn't want you to be under the impression you needed to use `:before` **and** `:after` to achieve your goals. More maintainable when working with one element versus two. Though you might if you wanted the boarder prior to hovering. Looking back I think that's what you were getting at.